# Ansible UFW allow outgoing, deny incoming

Tags: firewall, ansible, ufw

try to roll out UFW via Ansible.

```yaml
- name: Install UFW Firwall
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: UFW enabled
      community.general.ufw:
        state: "enabled"
        policy: "deny"
```

I would like the outgoing rule to allow everything and the incoming to denied everything. I just don't see how to make this work, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it was really simple. Just add a `direction: outgoing`. So the full code is this:

```yaml
- name: Install UFW Firewall
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Outgoing allow
      community.general.ufw:
        state: enabled
        direction: outgoing
        policy: allow

    - name: Incoming deny
      community.general.ufw:
        state: enabled
        direction: incoming
        policy: deny
```